# Why is the figure moving to a next page?

Tags: floats, positioning

The first page of chapter is left blank, while the figure is drawn on the next page?

```
\chapter{Diagrams}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{user/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.6cm, fill=Cerulean, draw=none}}

\tikzset{usersAOI/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5cm, fill=Bittersweet!30, draw=none}}


\tikzset{object/.style={inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.4cm, minimum height=0.4cm, fill=WildStrawberry, draw=none}}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[usersAOI] at (5,6) {$A$};
\node[user] at (5,6) {$A$};
\node[user] at (7,6) {};
\node[user] at (6,4.5) {};
\node[object] at (6.5,5.5) {};
\node[object] at (5.2,4.5) {};

\node[user] at (6,1.5) {};

\node[user] at (8,3) {};
\node[user] at (10,3) {};
\node[object] at (9,3) {};

\node[user] at (10,7.5) {};
\node[user] at (12,7.5) {};
\node[user] at (10,6) {};
\node[user] at (12,6) {};
\node[user] at (11,7) {};
\node[object] at (11,6.2) {};

\node[user] at (15.5,6) {};
\node[draw,align=left] at (15.5,5) {zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz};
\node[object] at (15.5,4) {};
\node[draw,align=left] at (15.5,3) {iiiiiiiiiiii};
\draw (15.5,2) [fill=Bittersweet!30] circle (0.3cm);
\node[draw,align=left] at (15.5,1) {zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz};


\end{tikzpicture}
\centering
\caption{uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a complete small document that shows the problem, and in particular which class you are using. figure replacement depends on what else is on the page, about which we have no information.

Comment: actually I m using a large template from my university...and its difficult to show here, can I do something else?

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce it with a standard class?

Comment: @user494461 try following the steps here to make an example just using book class that shows the same effect http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that#answer-3225